# Получение объекта python boost::python

Tags: c++, python, boost

Здравствуйте. Не могу разобраться с таким вопросом, как замапить объект из python в с++.
Если конкретно. Есть класс в с++:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void print_text()
    {
        puts("Hello C++");
    }
};
```

Его wrapper:

```
class MyClassWrap : public MyClass, public wrapper<MyClass>
{
    void print_text()
    {
        if (override print_text = this->get_override("f"))
#if BOOST_WORKAROUND(BOOST_MSVC, <= 1300)
            call<void>(print_text.ptr());
#else
            print_text();
#endif
        return MyClass::print_text();
    }
};
```

питоновский скрипт, где используется этот тип:

```
class MyPlugin(MyClass):
    def print_text(self):
        print "Hello Python"

plug = MyPlugin()
```

Как мне получить в с++ этот унаследованный MyPlugin как MyClass в с++. И вызывать функции предка.

Суть задачи имея какой-то класс в С++ унаследовать его в питоне и переопределить, методы предка, если это необходимо.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы разобрался. Но поправьте меня, если я где-то не точен.
Во первых необходимо исправить ошибку в классе MyClassWrap:

```
void print_text()
{
    if (override print_text = this->get_override("print_text"))
        print_text();
    else
        return MyClass::print_text();
}
```

А сам объект вызывается следующим образом:

```
auto res = main_namespace["plug"];
auto dictobj = (MyClassWrap &)extract<MyClassWrap>(res);
dictobj.print_text();
```